# Use "crontab -l" in if statement to send mail if no crontab for {user}

Tags: bash, shell, cron, scripting

I am writing a scrip to send a email alert if no crontab is present for the user.

```bash
if [[ $(crontab -l) == "no crontab for {user}" ]]; then
    mailx ....
fi
```

But the script is ending at `crontab -l`, the body of the `if` statement is not being executed.

I tried to run `grep` on the output:

```
crontab -l | grep "no crontab for {user}"
```

did not work

Comment: Replace `crontab -l` with `crontab -l 2>&1` to redirect stderr to stdout.

Comment: You can easily verify it on the command line, that the error message is written to stderr, which you don't process in your script. However, testing the output is not a good idea anyway. As like nearly every well-behaved program, `crontab` sets a  non-zero exit code on error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use crontab's exit code:

```
if ! crontab -l 2>/dev/null 1>&2; then
  echo "no crontab";
else
  echo "crontab";
fi
```

Comment: Tried both your answers, they are working, Thank you.
I am beginner to shell scripting. If you don't mind, can you tell me why this works and not what I was trying

Comment: If there is no cronjob then `crontab -l` outputs its text `no crontab for ...` as error message to stderr (2) and you need to redirect stderr (2) to stdout (1) with something like `2>&1` to make it accessable for your string comparison. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams